# Length of the space between rays

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I am sorry in advance for the awkard phrasing.

Three rays $A, B,$ and $C$ originate from point $(x, y)$. Points $(a, b)$, $(c, d)$, and $(e, f)$ lie on a straight line *and* lie on rays $A, B,$ and $C$ respectively. If these points are equidistant from each other, does that mean that *any* three points that lie on a line *and* lie on those three rays will be equidistant from each other?

Edit: I am asking because of this: [image: [picture](https://imgur.com/a/SaxG1)]

Is this distance $y$ special in the sense that there is only ONE distance $y$ that is the same between rays $1,2$ and $2,3$?